# Amazon Alexa Error Parsing Feed

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to create an Amazon Flash Briefing, keep receiving a error each time I try to upload the JSON feed:

> There was an error parsing the feed. Please ensure that the feed is valid JSON or RSS.

I have tested the JSON file multiple times on other validaters and receive similar errors on both (used [Free Formatter](https://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html) and [JSON Formatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)):

> The JSON input is NOT valid according to RFC 4627 (JSON specification). Unexpected token at position 764.

and

> Error:Invalid encoding, expecting UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32.

Now, I copy and paste the JSON code directly into these validaters, it works fine and validates. However, when I save the file as a JSON and upload it, I get these errors. I am extremely confused.

Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
    [
       {
          "uid": "b21d6146-1b88-11e8-accf-0ed5f89f718b",
          "updateDate": "2018-02-250T00:00:00.0Z",
          "titleText": "Jocko Flash Briefings - February 26",
          "mainText": "",
          "streamUrl": "https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/jocko-flashbriefing/How+to+Control+the+Fight+or+Flight+Response+-+Jocko+Willink.mp3",
          "redirectionUrl": "http://jockopodcast.com/"
       },
       {
          "uid": "b21d5e8a-1b88-11e8-accf-0ed5f89f718b",
          "updateDate": "2018-02-26T00:00:00.0Z",
          "titleText": "Jocko Flash Briefings - February 26",
          "mainText": "",
          "streamUrl": "https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/jocko-flashbriefing/NOT+Accepting+Weakness+-+Jocko+Willink.mp3",
          "redirectionUrl": "http://jockopodcast.com/"
       }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be a Unicode [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in your JSON file.

> The IETF recommends that if a protocol either (a) always uses UTF-8,
>   or (b) has some other way to indicate what encoding is being used,
>   then it “SHOULD forbid use of U+FEFF as a signature.”